# Firebase private rule not working for storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm trying to allow users to upload files to the firebase backend, I am using this rule: (the storage is filled in on my end)

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<storage>/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow write, read: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is just so I can see if it will block users from accessing the files I have open. But if I go to the link, I can see the image just fine.

How come this rule is not blocking users from viewing it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of a link that you can go to, that you expect to be protected by this?

Answer (score 3):

There are two different ways to download files from Firebase Storage:

- Downloaded via methods like `getFile()` or `writeToFile:` on a Storage reference.
- Storing an HTTP URL that you got from `getDownloadURL()` or `downloadURLWithCompletion:`.

If you download via the first method, we check security rules before allowing the download. This is the secure method for ACLing files to a user or group of users.

If you download via the second method, those URLs are public, unguessable URLs so anyone can access them and are only protected by the unguessability of the token at the end of the URL. This method is great for sharing files with users outside of your application (image Google Photos, where you want to send a photo to someone in your family but don't want to make them download an app to do so).

It sounds like you're using the second method, which as mentioned, doesn't check security rules. If you want to make files you can delete the download token in the Firebase console, or just never share those URLs with anyone.

Comment: Is there any way that we can make those URLs private or is Google just going for security by obscurity? It seems quite suspect to me.

Comment: @DevShadow Download URLs functions as a capability token: if you have the token, you have the capability to access the file. Many popular photo sharing apps use some form of capability token (often in the form of a signed URL).

Comment: The key to capability tokens is that they are sufficiently unguessable. In our case, we use UUIDs representing a randomly selected 128-bit number, meaning there are 2^128 = 3.4e38 distinct possibilities (and a 1/3.40282367e38 ~=0 probability of guessing it on your first try). Even if someone is guessing 1M photos a second (31.5T photos/year): you've still got 1.0e25 years before someone exhausts the search space. Even at 1B requests/second, it's still 1.0e22 years.

Comment: That this is the same general principle (substitute in really large prime numbers) that modern cryptography uses: technically you can factor said prime, but practically there's no way of doing it efficiently.